# How to define radius for blur with Python Pillow?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gaussianblur

I'm trying to blur an image with [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io), using [the ImageFilter](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/ImageFilter.html) as follows:

```
from PIL import ImageFilter
blurred_image = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

This works fine, except that it has a set radius which is way too small for me. I want to blur the image so much that it can be barely recognised anymore. In the docs I see that [the radius is set to 2 by default](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.2.x/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.GaussianBlur), but I don't really understand how I can set it to a larger value?

Does anybody have any idea how I could increase the blur radius with Pillow? All tips are welcome!

Comment: One of the interesting properties of a Gaussian blur is that when you run it multiple times, the result is a wider Gaussian blur. Try doing it twice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Image.filter()` takes an `ImageFilter` so you can create an `ImageFilter.GaussianBlur` instance with whatever radius you want, passed in as a named argument.

```
blurred_image = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=50))
```

You can even make it more concise like so:

```
blurred_image = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(50))
```

Comment: The version I'm still using (Image 1.1.7, Ubuntu 12.04) has a bug.  Parameter is ignored.  Workaround: `filter = ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(); filter.radius=50`, `blurred_image = im.filter(filter)`.  Just to save you the searching in case you've got the same problem as I had.

Comment: I've just asked [For PIL.ImageFilter.GaussianBlur how what kernel is used and does the radius parameter relate to standard deviation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62968174/3904031)